# User nulls last message was null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to get a discord.js command to say a user's last message, but it returned the message
User nulls last message was null.

Code :

```
switch (args[0]) {
  case 'lastmessage':
    let user = msg.mentions.members.first();
    console.log(msg.author.username);
    msg.channel.send(`User ${user.nickname}s last message was ${user.lastMessage}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.lastMessage` isn't a property of `user`, but of `msg.guild.member(user)`

So to fix your error:

```
case 'lastmessage' :
  let user = msg.mentions.members.first();
  console.log(msg.author.username)
  msg.channel.send("User ${user.nickname}s last message was ${msg.guild.member(user).lastMessage}")
```

This would only send the last message that the bot picks up, though, so if you restart your bot,  and the person you mention did not send a message after you restarted it, it would still be null. To prevent this, you could check if the property is null

```js
let lastMsg = msg.guild.member(user).lastMessage
if (!lastMsg) return msg.channel.send("That user hasn't sent a message since the last tim the bot restarted!")
//and then the rest
```